# Mining computer graphics driver yes or no?

Tags: mining-hardware

Im about to add a second graphics card to my computer to enhance its mining capability. My question is, should i install the graphics driver for the new card even though it is not needed to run the pc and will only be used for mining?

Answer (score 0):

install the driver to get better performance even if you are not using it for graphic rendering but for mining. you could use tools like Nvidia inspector if you are using Nvidia card to get the details of your mining card.